# Create CSV for import from File directories?

Tags: import, bulk-import, csv

Lets say I have posts sorted in individual folders with a word document & jpg inside.

What would be the best way to sort that into a csv for import.
I assume some excel script or such.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Sorting folders of `.doc` and `.jpg` files into `CSV` file(s) looks like some fairly heavy lifting to me. What do you have to work with? Bash shell? Python? Perl? PHP? Java? What? Whatever it is it is unlikely to be WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

simple batch file would do that:

DIR %1 /B /S >files.csv

Save as a bat file and place it in the root directory.

Run the bat and will output directories and file names to files.csv same location as the bat file.

Comment: Your answer makes assumptions about the operating system in use. Please state the caveats clearly.